# Chart.js set active segment on initialize

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm working with chart.js v2 and I am trying simulate the hover state of a segment on a doughnut graph when the chart loads so it appears there is a section alright highlighted.

I've been searching and combing the code for a day now and can't figure out a good way to do this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

Setting a segment's hover style is a bit confusing because its not really documented anywhere.  Nevertheless, I was able to figure it out a while back when I wanted to highlight a segment when it's legend label was hovered.

To do this, you need to use the pie chart `.updateHoverStyle()` prototype method and pass in the segment you want highlighted.  The chart segments are stored in the `_meta` object in an array where each segment index matches the position of each value in your chart's data array.

Here is an example (assuming your chart instance is stored in a var called `myPie`.

```
// get the segment we want to highlight
var activeSegment = myPie.data.datasets[0]._meta[0].data[segmentIndexToHihlight];

// update the hover style
myPie.updateHoverStyle([activeSegment], null, true);

// render so we can see it
myPie.render();
```

You just need to define what segment you want to highlight and store it in a var called `segmentIndexToHihlight` and it should work.

Here is a [codepen example](http://codepen.io/jordanwillis/pen/bqoqKb) demonstrating this.  Note, I purposely did not highlight the segment on load (I wait 3 seconds) so that you can see the change occur.

Comment: nice find, i wish they documented any of this

Answer (score 0):

I found another way to preselect a segment, basically you can simulate a click event on the point. You can find in the dataset model the position x and y. Here you can find my solution:

```
function simulateClick(x, y) {
  const clickEvent = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
  clickEvent.initMouseEvent('click', true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, x, y, 
  false, false, false, false, 0, null);
  document.elementFromPoint(x, y).dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
}

function initActivePoint(index) {
  const activePoint = myChart.data.datasets[0]._meta[0].data[index];
  simulateClick(activePoint._model.x, activePoint._model.y);
}

initActivePoint(0);
```